# How to implement this logic using Streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I want to change the following code into a stream. Functionality should be the same, but I want to do it with streams.

```
public static String getGlobalPreviewDesc(List<Project> projectDataMap) {
    StringBuilder globalPreviewDesc = new StringBuilder();
    for (Project project : projectDataMap) {
        globalPreviewDesc.append(project.preview_description);
    }
    System.out.println(globalPreviewDesc);

    return globalPreviewDesc.toString();
}
```

Comment: `return projectDataMap.stream().map(p -> p.preview_description).peek(System.out::println).collect(Collectors.joining());` Please don't shout.

Answer (score 0):

For that, you have to invoke `stream()` method on the given list of projects. Then turn the stream of projects `Stream<Project>` into a stream of string by of strings by passing `Stream<String>` the following [*lambda expression*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) (or [*method reference*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html)) into a `map` operation:

```
project -> project.getPreviewDescription() // or Project::getPreviewDescription
```

*Note that in Java (*contrary to other languages*), preferred way to access object properties is by using **getters**. And by [convention](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) names of methods and variables should be written in camel-case starting with lower-case letter.*

In order to join stream elements into a single `String` apply `collect` as a terminal operation by passing `Collectors.joining` as an argument.

I assume you didn't want all the descriptions to jumbled together without any delimiters (*that is what your code does*), but rather intended to separate them somehow. Therefore, the following code uses newline `"\n"` as a delimiter.

```
public static String getGlobalPreviewDesc(List<Project> projectDataMap) {
    return projectDataMap.stream()               // Stream<Project>
            .map(Project::getPreviewDescription) // Stream<String>
            .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
}
```

[*For more information on streams take a look at this tutorial*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/)